# How to set a .vimrc file by default

Tags: linux, vim

On my linux i have a lot of .vimrc files.
One of this in `/etc/vimrc`
Second in `~/.vim/.vimrc`
so when i type `echo $MYVIMRC` there is nothing
help me to set my `~/.vim/.vimrc` by default so when i will open a file that script must be loaded

Comment: Vim will look for `~/.vim/vimrc` (no dot before the file!) by default. See `:help vimrc`. I.e. you just need to get rid of that dot and things will work.

Answer (score -1):

To set your `~/.vim/.vimrc` as the default configuration file for Vim, you can do the following:

1. Open your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` file in a text editor. You can use Vim or any other text editor you prefer. For example:

```bash
vim ~/.bashrc
```

2. Add the following line to the file to set `~/.vim/.vimrc` as the default configuration file for Vim:

```bash
export MYVIMRC="$HOME/.vim/.vimrc"
```

3. Save the file and exit the text editor.
4. To make the changes take effect immediately, you can either source the `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` file or open a new terminal session:

```bash
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now, when you open a file with Vim, it should automatically load the configuration from `~/.vim/.vimrc`.

You can test this by opening Vim and checking if `:echo $MYVIMRC` now returns `~/.vim/.vimrc`.

Comment: This is very wrong.